# How to provide values for graphlql query variables in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, graphql

I am trying to provide a value for a variable in a graphql query but it's not working.

```
const queryInfo = {
query: `query($username: String!){
        user(login: $username){
        name
        bio
        avatarUrl
        repositories(first: 20){
        nodes{
        name
        url
        forkCount
        stargazerCount
        updatedAt
        languages(first: 20) {
          nodes{
            name
          }
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
        `,
        {username: "japhmayor"}


};
  const url = "https://api.github.com/graphql";
  const token = "my token is here";
  const options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Authorization: "bearer " + token,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(queryInfo),
  };
```

[image: I have a red line on line 38]
[image: Query works well in explorer but i dont know how to provide represent the query variables in code editor]

the query works well if i hardcode the username. How do i provide the value for the username variable?

Comment: What happens with the code as it is? Do you get errors?

Comment: Yes. the fetch doesnt go through because username is undefined.

Comment: variables requires variables object - use playground to test mutation, explore request details

Comment: My query works well in github api explorer but  dont know how to provide the variable values in my code editor

Comment: just find the difference between 2 requests

Answer (score 0):

Your `queryInfo` needs a `variables` object as well, which is where you define the variables for the query. It would look like this:

```js
const queryInfo = {
    query: `query($username: String!) {
                ..
           }`,
    variables: {
        username: 'japhmayor'
    }
}
```

See the last example in [the docs](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/passing-arguments/)